# How to determine height of a Flutter TextFormField?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textformfield

I have **TextFormField** in  **Container** and I want to align the **error message** at the bottom of the **Container**, but the **error message** is a little away from the **TextFormField**. And the **error message** should show up in the **Container**.

How can I determine the height from the **TextFormField**?

```
Form(
     key: _formkey1,
     child:
     Column(children: [
     Stack(
     clipBehavior: Clip.none,
       children:[ Container(
         width: 990.w,
         height: 203.w,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0.w),
           border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12),
         ),
         child: Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(46.w, 38.w, 0, 35.w),
             child:
                 Text(
                   'Current Password',
                   style: FONT_CONST.MEDIUM
                       .copyWith(fontSize: 34.w,
                       color: COLOR_CONST.color_9e9e9e),
                 ),),),
         Positioned(
             left: 46.w,
             top: 105.w,
             child:
                 Container(
                   width: 881.w,
                   height: 187.w,
                     child: TextFormField(
                       obscureText: true,
                       validator: (value) {
                         if (value!.isEmpty) {
                           return "empty";
                         }
                         if (value!=_myInfoProvider.my.password){
                           return "Please enter your current password";
                         }
                         else {
                           return null;
                         }
                       },
                       style: FONT_CONST.MEDIUM.copyWith(
                           fontSize: 46.w),
                       decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                           hintText: 'Enter Current Password',
                           hintStyle: FONT_CONST.MEDIUM
                               .copyWith(fontSize: 46.w,
                               color: COLOR_CONST.color_c8cacb)),
                       controller: _textEditingController1,
                     ),
                   ),)
                 ]),
```

I used the **Stack** widget because the **Form** widget in the **Container**  can't return the **error message** out of **Container**.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the error message to show up at the bottom of the field ?

Comment: try adding a screenshot to your question to be more detailed !

Comment: thank you I had add picture!! I want to align error message like this, but it work align in the container.  so I try erorMessage space out from textfield. finally edited code to

Comment: return "\n"
                                  "Please enter your current password";

Comment: and success!!!! thanks for  trying to help 

Comment: good, if you do not want to use \n , then check out my answer below it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your issue, you want to show the error message in a different position.

Depending on your code, you can use setState to show the error message in another widget.

Simply add a variable for your error message:

```
Text errorMsg;
```

and call setState in the validator :

```
                   child: TextFormField(
                       obscureText: true,
                       validator: (value) {
                         if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                            errorMsg = Text('empty');
                          });
                           return "";
                         }
                         if (value!=_myInfoProvider.my.password){
                            setState(() {
                            errorMsg = Text('Please enter your current password');
                          });
                           return "";
                         }
                         else {
                            setState(() {
                            errorMsg = null;
                          });
                           return null;
                         }
                       },
                       style: FONT_CONST.MEDIUM.copyWith(
                           fontSize: 46.w),
```

Finally, add the error message to a new Positioned Widget in the Stack :

```
                ///your Poisitioned Widget
                Positioned(....),
                /// Add this and change the values to the position that you demand
                if(errorMsg != null)
                Positioned(
                  left: 46.w,
                  top: 120.w,
                  child: errorMsg,
                ),
```

Comment: OMG good idea thankyou!! I try only one way that directly return errorMessage.. It's better than use "\n" : )  thankyou for your help